# C# & MySQL search on multiple fields

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am trying to search on multiple fields in an WPF application. I have the table

[image]

In my app I have a window in which I have few Check Boxes: 
[image]

Question: How can I make sql request to search by 1 value (for example, date), a few values (date & name OR date & status OR status & date) or for all values?

Comment: If you are doing this on the Database side.. I would create a stored procedure assigning the Input params = to `Null` then in the query create a sql statement using selecting on the params using the `ISNULL` if all values are null return everything if Date is selected etc.. does this make sense..?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot) I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are passing these values in to a query (Stored Procedure) of some description you will want to compare the data in the database to either the value you provide as a parameter (indicated using a @), or to null, i.e.

```
SELECT field1
FROM myTable
WHERE (myTable.StartDate < @StartDate) OR (@StartDate is NULL)
AND (myTable.Client = @Client) OR (@Client IS NULL)
AND ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do it.

Comment: Brilliant - Let us know how you get on and if you need further help

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I tried to do it your way. Working. But in the end I use a stored procedure.